# Mac command batch not finding file

Tags: bash, macos, osx-yosemite, macos-catalina

Ok I got a mac os command which works fine

```
security import "/Users/xxx/Documents/AppCompiler/temp/CordovaBuildFiles/Certificates/IOSRelease/ios_Production.p12" -k "$KEYCHAIN" -P "PASSWORD" -A
```

But if I want to make it a little dynamic by storing the P12 into a variable it fails with 'No such file or directoryile ios_Production.p12'

```
CERT="/Users/xxx/Documents/AppCompiler/temp/CordovaBuildFiles/Certificates/IOSRelease/ios_Production.p12" 
security import "$CERT" -k "$KEYCHAIN" -P "$PASSWORD" -A
```

I have also tried setting $CERT="ios_Production.p12" and moving to the folder before calling.

Can anyone share any light on what can cause this to happen?

**Updated as Mark Setchell pointed out a code error - thanks mark in the original. I have also altered the folder where it is stored.

There full error returned is:
security: Error reading infile /Users/xxx/Documents/AppCompiler/temp/Cordov: No such file or directorySRelease/ios_Production.p12

#### Further UPDATE and is now working but I dont understand WHY???

OK I decided to move ios_Production.p12 into Documents folder and it worked, so I created another CERT line then folder by folder added them back in and for reasons I am really confused about it now works. Below are the two lines:

cert="/Users/xxx/Documents/AppCompiler/temp/CordovaBuildFiles/Certificates/IOSRelease/ios_Production.p12"

cert="/Users/xxx/Documents/AppCompiler/temp/CordovaBuildFiles/Certificates/IOSRelease/ios_Production.p12"

You will be forgiven for thinking you are seeing double because you are 100%, I have compared them in a diff checker but depending which line is commented out depends if the import works or not. I really hope this makes some form of sense to someone because I'm going bald here...

Comment: That sounds like you have something like a non printing character in there messing things up. Try printing the script file with `LC_ALL=C cat -vet /path/to/script` and see if those lines still look identical. BTW, you should see a dollar-sign added to the end of each line indicating the newline character. If you see something else unusual, that’s a hint that something is weird.

Comment: Try going to the directory ending in `.p12` and running `pwd | xxd` to see if there is a mad character in your directory name in the word `Cordova`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon - both outputs using LC_ALL are the same.

Comment: Mark - It happens even if i set the folder to /users/documents so its not a folder issue. Anything I alter on that line fails but an exact new line works (typed not copied) - I think Gordon has the right thought of something being hidden within but its not showing up anywhere. Fix is simply delete the line but its a head scratcher...

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this:

```
CERT="/Users/xxx/Documents/AppCompiler/keys/prod/prodx.p12" 
security import "$CERT" -k "$KEYCHAIN" -P "$PASSWORD" -A
```

The syntax is like this. If you set a shell variable, do this with no dollar and no spaces:

```
variable="..."
```

If you access the contents of a variable, surround with double quotes and use a dollar:

```
echo "$variable"
```

And, in general, avoid variables names consisting of upper case letters to be sure not to clash with built-in variables, so your `CERT` should really be `cert`, but that is not really the point here.

Comment: thanks worked a treat and ill keep an eye on those $$$$$$$

Comment: I spoke too soon - it worked to pull in the variable but the original problem remains. If I place anything in to a variable it gets rejected with No such file or directoryile.

Comment: Maybe you could click `edit` under your question and update it to match your current, best code and include the error messages...